# Raspberry PI? Should questions about it be allowed, and should it get a tag?

Tags: discussion, scope

Just discovered this beta, it looks right up my alley. I'm wondering users can ask questions on the Raspberry Pi, as it can be used to emulate older hardware.

Answer (score 9):

Welcome to the site, we're glad you found us.

However, the answer is a definite maybe.
Raspberry Pi questions are probably not directly suitable for this site.

There is the [Raspberry Pi StackExchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) site, where there are already questions regarding using it for emulation of older equipment.  I use it that way myself at home.

On the other hand, questions regarding which features of an old machine can be emulated, and how, are suitable here.

There is overlap between StackExchange sites and no hard and fast rules as to which site is *correct* for any given question.  I'm not saying don't post here - we always welcome good questions.  I just suggest that the Raspberry Pi site may have more experts in using it as an emulator.

Please ask away - on whichever site you feel is most appropriate.

And while you're here, any expertise you have is always welcome in answering questions!

Answer (score 9):

Generally I would say questions about Raspberry Pi are off-topic, as it is a modern piece of hardware.  It would be on-topic for [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) as mentioned by Chenmunka.  I don't think a specific tag for Raspberry Pi questions is appropriate here.

If you have a general emulation question, it would probably be on-topic here.  Generally retro software emulators are hardware agnostic, and a problem you see on a Raspberry Pi (installing or running software, etc.), might be reproducible on other environments as well.